# Hover background image doesn't work IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to fix a issue with IE 11 about my hover thing.

Basically, when I mouse over the link, the text background changes.

Everything works fine with FireFox and Google Chrome. However, the background image doesn't appear with Internet Explorer 11.

```css
ul .news:hover {
  background: url("Images/OverNews.png");
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="news"><a href="#"> News </a></li>
   <li class="chat"><a href="#"> Chat </a></li>
   <li class="forum"><a href="#"> Forum </a></li>
   <li class="contact"><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code you are sharing is fine. Should work in Internet Explorer 6 !! Add the complete code because maybe you are overriding something, or changing <li> elements to inline, or something similar.

Comment: I created a codepen with your example, and it does seem to be working in ie11. That said, I'm experiencing this same issue, so there must be some other mitigating factor.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My solution was to set the HTML element to a block element. But in my case the background image was on the **anchor tag**. Try

```
.news {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ul .news:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/OverNews.png");
}
```